# Should I always prefer MySQL InnoDB over MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, database-design, innodb, myisam

Someone just told me that InnoDB is much better than MyISAM. So when I create a table, should I *always* try to use InnoDB Engine instead of MyISAM? Or do both have it's big benefits?

Comment: http://www.mikebernat.com/blog/MySQL_-_InnoDB_vs_MyISAM

Answer (score 35, accepted):

`MyISAM` is transactionless and heap-organized. The records are identified by the row offset in the table and the indexes store this offset as a row pointer.

`InnoDB` supports transactions and is index-organized. The records are identified by the value of the `PRIMARY KEY` (or a hidden internal column is there is no `PRIMARY KEY` defined) and are stored in a `B-Tree`. The secondary indexes store the value of the `PRIMARY KEY` as a row pointer.

Queries that involve full table scans or secondary index lookups are usually faster on `MyISAM` tables.

Queries that involve `PRIMARY KEY` seeks are usually faster on `InnoDB` tables.

`MyISAM` tables store the number of records in the table in the table's metadata, that's why the queries like this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(*)
FROM    myisamtable
```

are instant.

`MyISAM` tables are completely locked on the `DML` operations (with several exceptions).

`InnoDB` tables lock individual records and index gaps, however these are the records and the gaps that are scanned, not only those matched by the `WHERE` condition. This can lead to the records being locked despite the fact they don't match.

`InnoDB` tables support referential integrity (`FOREIGN KEY`s) . `MyISAM` tables don't.

There are several scenarios that can show benefits of both engines.

Answer (score 12):

Simple answer: No, you shouldn't.

A few points about each engine:

**InnoDB**

- Full support for Foreign Key restraints and transactions. *(ACID compliant)*
- Row-level locking.
- Arguably faster INSERT statements. *(And possibly UPDATE as well)*

**MyISAM**

- Faster SELECT statements.
- Support for Full-Text searches
- BLOB and TEXT columns can be indexed
- 4x max storage limit, compared to InnoDB (256TB vs 64TB)

See more in the Manual:

- [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/myisam-storage-engine.html)
- [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb.html)

Answer (score 9):

To put it simply:

You should use InnoDB:

- if you need transaction support
- if you need foreign keys

You should use MyISAM:

- if you don't need the above AND
- you need speed (faster database operations)

Comment: You might want to read this http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/08/innodb-vs-myisam-vs-falcon-benchmarks-part-1/ about speed.

Answer (score 4):

IMHO you should always prefer `InnoDB` over `MyISAM` because of the transactional support which is at the heart of every relational database system.

Answer (score 1):

InnoDB is a fully ACID compliant database engine and therefore offers support for transactions, etc. As such, it can therefore be slower than the MyISAM database which tends to be optimised in a different direction.

Therefore if you need transactions InnoDB (or another RDBMS such as PostgreSQL) is the obvious choice.

There's a reasonable comparison over on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InnoDB)

Answer (score 0):

You could use both. You could use InnoDB for your write database/transactions, but read back from an MyISAM database, which is denormalized. This gives the best of both worlds. You know you're data is safe with referential integrity from InnoDB, and you can read it as fast as you'd like with MyISAM.

Comment: Can you please refer to a link on how to use both engines