# innodb and myisam in mysql database

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MyISAM versus InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb)

what is the difference between innodb and myisam ? i see both of them as a type of engine in my mysql database.

Comment: try this [http://serverfault.com/questions/54897/what-is-the-difference-between-innodb-and-myisam](http://serverfault.com/questions/54897/what-is-the-difference-between-innodb-and-myisam)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277440/mysql-myisam-vs-inno-db

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970160/should-i-always-prefer-mysql-innodb-over-myisam

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that InnoDB supports transactions, but MyISAM does not.

Comment: referential integrity too.  But Full Text Search is only supported on MyISAM...

Comment: Typically MyISAM is used for logging tables, while InnoDB is much better suited for tables with important data that needs to maintain integrity.