# How can I choose the mysql database engine? InnoDB or MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I always prefer MySQL InnoDB over MyISAM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970160/should-i-always-prefer-mysql-innodb-over-myisam)

I just wanna know in what situation we will use MyISAM? in what situation we will use INnoDB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1970160/should-i-always-prefer-mysql-innodb-over-myisam

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/09/mysql-engines-innodb-vs-myisam-a-comparison-of-pros-and-cons.html

http://tag1consulting.com/MySQL_Engines_MyISAM_vs_InnoDB

There are many differences, data integrity, locks, transactions to name a few, for good design u may wanna go through these links once. Pros and Cons are mentioned in detail in a simplistic manner

Comment: +1 Good links, but you could place the main pros / cons within your answer.

Comment: thanks, will definitely keep in mind... @Tadeck

Answer (score 0):

A very basic run-down of my decision-making is: "table-lock = MyISAM, row-lock = InnoDB".

Of course there's more to it than that, but that's all that really matters for me.